# Does fluent wait work with Page Factory Web Elements in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, page-factory

I am thinking that page factory web elements don't work with fluent wait. I have the following case where I am waiting for the presense of an element and it doesn't seem to work when using page factory web elements

```
public class HomePage
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submitBtn")]
    public IWebElement SubmitBtn { get; private set; }

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Test class using Page Factory

```
public class HomePageTests : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {   
        base.Driver = base.InitDriver();
        HomePage homePage = new(Driver);
       
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));  
        
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(homePage.SubmitBtn()));
        homePage.SubmitBtn.Click();
    }
}
```

Test class using By locator

```
public class HomePageTests : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {   
        base.Driver = base.InitDriver();
        HomePage homePage = new(Driver);
       
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));            
        
        var submitBtn = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("submitBtn"));
        submitBtn.Click();
    }
}
```

It seems to work on not using the page factory web element but passing a locator. I've been testing it consistenty for a period of time and wondering if page factory web elements are initalized different to using by locator (I am aware of the lazy load but could that be part of the reason?).

EDIT
The exception I get is NoSuchElementException

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't seem to work when using page factory web elements"? If you are getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace as plain text.

Comment: Use only the elements that are useful in your page factory objects.  If DOM is updated via Javascript you're going to need to use a webdriverwait and that means either creating an object/class that holds those methods (without findsby annotations), or writing the code outside of re-usable objects.  I believe FindsBy annotation will use a standard findelement method when initElements method is called.  (without a wait)  If you are only concerned with presence of the element, then setting an implicitwait (global) will help, but you should not mix implicit/explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding elements using the PageFactory annotations immediately tries to find the element the moment you call the property. Depending on how you configured the web driver, it will return the `IWebElement` object or throw a NoSuchElementException immediately.

You can configure the web driver with [implicit waits](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/implicit-wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver-c/), but that only works to prevent NoSuchElementExceptions the first time you try to find the element. *It does not ensure Selenium can interact with that element.* Nor does it ensure the element is still attached to the HTML document the next time you need to access a property or call a method on the `IWebElement` object.

Instead, use the [expression-bodied member syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0025) for properties that return an `IWebElement` or collection of `IWebElement` objects. Lastly, when you need to wait for something, use an [explicit wait](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/).

You can combine all of these requirements into one property, making your page model simpler:

```
public class HomePage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;
    private readnly WebDriverWait wait;

    private IWebElement SubmitButton => wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("submitBtn")));

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    public PageAfterSubmit Submit()
    {
        SubmitButton.Click();

        return new PageAfterSubmit(driver);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. The page model pattern should expose **methods** that encapsulate some user action. Do not expose IWebElement properties. This breaks the abstraction provided by the page model.
2. When a user action should change the page, consider returning an instance of a *different* page model that represents the updated page.
3. A method named "Submit" is very generic. It is not a meaningful name for the use case it models. Consider changing the name of this method to match the use case. The button might be named "submitBtn", but what use case does this represent? That should guide you to a better name.

Comment: This is a basic example but yes I put this as an example. I have a wrapper class between my tests and elements that handle the element functionality (clicking an element, filling text to a textbox, etc). My question is regarding to your first point - does explicit waits work well with Page Factory? This is more what I am trying to find out? Thank you for the explanation.